# Write api e2e tests as a spring boot service using serenity bdd

Tags: cucumber, serenity-bdd

1. Write end2end api tests as a service and deploy that as a service and anyone can hit that service inside or outside of our team to trigger the tests. In response they will receive the test results not just status code.
2. To do this I want to use serenity bdd for writing tests with cucumber and generate serenity report
3. At high level, what it means is all the tests will live in the src/main folder instead of src/test folder

I know this is not how end2end tests are done usually. In api ene2end tests we would usually hit an end point and generate a report.

IS THIS POSSIBLE AT ALL ?

I have successfully wrote an api end2end test as a service and anyone inside or outside the team can access this end point to trigger the tests and they will receive the status whether the tests were triggered or not.
My expectation is
When someone triggers the tests by hitting the endpoint in response they should get serenity report.
Secondly, I should be able to write my test in cucumber